# Need to be able to input more words

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to make my macro bring up a search box that allows me to enter as many words as I want, separated by comma, and then find each word in the list in the document and make them bold and blue.  What I have right now actually DOES exactly what I want it to do.  It finds each word that I enter into the searchbox (separated by commas), finds the word, and changes it to bold blue font.

The problem is this:  I need to be able to enter a page or more of words.  InputBox only gives me 255 characters to use at a time.  Is there a modification to make to my code to be able to have no limit to the number of words I can paste in to change?

It doesn't help that I am new at this. It has taken me a day and a half to get where I am right now.

```
Sub BlueWords()
  Dim blueword As String
  Dim numberofwords As Long

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  ' Enter words that need to become bold blue words.
  blueword = InputBox("Enter items to be found here,seperated by comma: ", "Items to be found")
  numberofwords = UBound(Split(blueword, ","))

 ' Find each item and replace it with new one respectively.
  For numberofwords = 0 To numberofwords
    With Selection
      .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
      With Selection.Find
        .Text = Split(blueword, ",")(numberofwords)
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
        .Replacement.Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
        .Format = True
        .MatchWholeWord = True
      End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
Next numberofwords

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

It works.  I just need to be able to input more than 255 characters of words at a time.  I need "no limit".

Comment: Have you tried using a form and textbox on the form instead of an InputBox? An InputBox is limited to 255 characters. It will require a bit more coding.

Comment: A possible alternative to the UserForm approach would be to write the list in another document. Then the `blueword` line could be changed to something like: `blueword = Documents("NAme").Content.Text`. (Note that you'd need to cut off the last character - a paragraph mark - but if the approach is acceptable that's a very simple thing to do.

Comment: Very interesting.  I will try that.  The words are coming from another document anyway.  This could actually save me a step.

Answer (score 1):

Add a user form instead, then add a button and a text box (there is no limit on text boxes in forms) then set the button to run the macro taking the input from the forms text box

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub BlueWords()
  Dim blueword As String
  Dim numberofwords As Long

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  ' Enter words that need to become bold blue words.
  UserForm1.Show

  'blueword = The super long input string in the userform
  blueword = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text
  numberofwords = UBound(Split(blueword, ","))

 ' Find each item and replace it with new one respectively.
  For numberofwords = 0 To numberofwords
    With Selection
      .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
      With Selection.Find
        .Text = Split(blueword, ",")(numberofwords)
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
        .Replacement.Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
        .Format = True
        .MatchWholeWord = True
      End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
Next numberofwords

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  Unload UserForm1

End Sub
```